# How can I make a tablesorter use a single filter input?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter-enabled table, which is working fine, but I want to make use of the filter widget. I understand that the default behaviour is to add an input field for each column, but I was looking for a way to instead have a single "search" input, outside of the table that would filter on all columns.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quicksearch](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) is a stand-alone plugin that will work with tablesorter.